# How to use Flickr4Java on Android device

Tags: android, flickr

I am trying to use Flickr4Java on an Android device. One of the required libraries for Flickr4Java is log4j. When I instantiate the Flickr object as below:

```
Flickr f = new Flickr(API_KEY, API_SECRET, new REST());
```

I get the following error:

```
java.lang.VerifyError: org/apache;log4j/config/PropertySetter
```

Any suggestions on how to proceed from here?